# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

Hello to the whole community.

I am doing a project in which the restaurants in my city can place their dishes and generate orders through the Application.

But I am having an error with my project when executing it.

This is the mistake I am having.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s  
Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`., , 
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:767)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:676)
    in FlatList (at Meals.tsx:14)
    in RCTView (at Meals.tsx:12)
    in Meals (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:900)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:100)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:131)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:900)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:100)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:131)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at withExpoRoot.js:26)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:25)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

I am doing the project on my frontend with React-native.

**My code is this - my frontend **

***App.js***

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import MealsScreen from './src/screens/Meals';
import Modal from './src/screens/Modal';

const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  Meals: {
    screen: MealsScreen
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Meals'
});

const RootStack = createStackNavigator( {
  Main: AppNavigation,
  Modal: Modal,
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
});

export default createAppContainer( RootStack );
```

***Meals***

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';
import UseFetch from '../hooks/useFetch';

const Meals = ({navigation}) => {
    const { loading, data: meals } = UseFetch('https://serverless.mgyavega.now.sh/api/meals');

    return(
        <View style =  { styles.container }>
            { loading ? <Text style =  { styles.text }>Cargando por favor espere...</Text> :
                <FlatList
                    style = { styles.list }
                    data = { meals }
                    keyExtractor= { x => x.id }
                    renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                        <ListItem
                            onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('Modal', { id: item.id })}
                            name = { item.name }
                        />
                    }
                />
            }
        </View>
    )
}

Meals.navigationOptions = ({
    title: 'Comidas Disponibles',
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
    list: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    },
    text: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

export default Meals;
```

Create a list that calls the Flatlist action and manage the information on my list.

***List.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import {  TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default ({ name, onPress }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = { onPress } style={ styles.container }>
            <Text style = { styles.text }> {name} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        height: 60,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#eee'
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 16
    }
});
```

Get the url of my project.

***UseFecth.js***

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const UseFetch = ( url ) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const [ data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {

        const response = await fetch(url);

        const data  = await response.json();

        setData(data);

        setLoading(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [] );

    return { loading, data }
}

export default UseFetch;
```

***My modal.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import {  View, Text, } from 'react-native';
import UseFetch from '../hooks/useFetch';

export default ({navigation}) => {

    const id = navigation.getParam('_id');
    const { loading, data } = UseFetch(`https://serverless.mgyavega.now.sh/api/meals/${id}`);

    console.log( 'Información del id del menú: ', id );

    return (

        loading ? <Text>Cargando </Text> :
            <View>
                <Text>  </Text>
                <Text>  </Text>
            </View>

    )
}
```

I am doing my backend with MongoDB, Ziet and Node.js.

This is my route.

***index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var meals = require('./routes/meals');
var orders = require('./routes/orders');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } );

app.use('/api/meals', meals);
app.use('/api/orders', orders);

module.exports = app;
```

***Meals.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var Meals = require('../models/meals');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', ( req, res ) => {
    Meals.find()
         .exec()
         .then( x => {
             res.status(200).send(x)
    });
});

router.get('/:id', ( req, res ) => {
    Meals.findById(req.params.id)
         .exec()
         .then( x => {
             res.status(200).send(x);
    });
});
```

***Models.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Meal = mongoose.model('Meal', new Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: String,
}));

module.exports = Meal;
```

I don't know why the information is duplicating me.

I appreciate the collaboration you can give me.

Thank you.

Mario

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that this line is producing duplicate key's.

```
keyExtractor= { x => x.id }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and how could I do so that this line does not duplicate, try removing it but sell me the following error. Virtualized list: keys are missing for the elements, be sure to specify a key or identification property in each element or provide a custom key extractor.

Answer (score 0):

In this line, keyExtractor= { x => x.id } the id might have been duplicated. 
Eg.
[{"id":1,"name":"hello"},{"id":1,"name":"world"}] 
Both the values have same ids.

Try keyExtractor= { x => x } if all the values in the list are unique
Otherwise you can use any property in a list. Eg .keyExtractor= { x => x.name }

Comment: Thanks for your help, probe the but I am getting the following error. keyExtractor = {x => x} Warning: Found two children with the same key, `% s`. The keys must be unique for the components to maintain their identity in the updates. Non-unique keys can cause children to duplicate or omit; the behavior is not compatible and could change in a future version.% S, [Object object],

Answer (score -1):

The problem with using database ids as keys is that depending on your query, your database can return rows with duplicate ids. 
I use uuid (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) in my projects, it works like a charm!

Comment: This is not a great idea. This will cause unnecessary re-renders. There is a reason react wants unique keys, not random keys.

Answer (score -1):

if someone has the same thing, the solution is the easiest.

In keyExtractor = {x => x.id} it is changed with keyExtractor = {x => x._id} since in the mongoDB database the id of each record is _id and as I was bringing it with id that gave me It was causing duplicity.

Everything else is correct.

He hoped he would help someone.